# axios - [Object Promise] when loading data from API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a VueJS template wherein the form will be pre-populated from a call from an API. The call is via an async function. After the response is received in a form of a string, the object returned is [object Promise]. Now I understand that async functions return a Promise object. However, I really don't know how to convert it to its real value.

```
async function getCitizen(id,name)
{
  const cnamed = await getData(id, name);
  return cnamed.CName;
}

async function getData(id, name)
{
  try {
    let res = await axios({
         url: 'http://localhost:44375/api/citizen/GetCitizenById',
         method: 'get',
         timeout: 8000,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
         params: 
         {
          citizen_id: id, 
          citizen_name: name
         }
     })
     if(res.status == 200){
         // test for status you want, etc
         console.log(res.status)
     }    
     // Don't forget to return something  
     return res.data
 }
 catch (err) {
     console.error(err);
 }

}


var citizenEdit = Vue.extend({
  template: '#citizen-edit',
  data: function () {
    const b = getCitizen(this.$route.params.citizen_id, this.$route.params.citizen_name);
    return {
      citizenselected: {CName : b} //returns [object Promise] instead of string
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updatecitizen: function () {
      {
        let uri = 'http://localhost:44375/api/citizen/UpdateCitizenDetails';
        axios.put(uri, this.citizenselected).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            router.push('/');
        });       
      };
    }
  }
});

<template id="citizen-edit">
    <section>
  <h2>Edit Citizen</h2>
  <form v-on:submit="updatecitizen">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-citizenid">Citizen ID</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="edit-citizenid" v-model="citizenselected.citizenid" disabled/>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="edit-name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="edit-name" v-model="citizenselected.CName" disabled/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="edit-gender">Gender</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="edit-gender" v-model="citizenselected.Gender" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-gender">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="edit-email" v-model="citizenselected.Email" required/>
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <router-link to="'/'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</router-link>
  </form>
</section>
</template>
```

**UPDATE:** I tried using `.then` but still gives me [object Promise]

```
var citizenEdit = Vue.extend({
  template: '#citizen-edit',
  data: function () {
    var b = getCitizen(this.$route.params.citizen_id, this.$route.params.citizen_name).then
    (result => b = result);
    return {
      citizenselected: {CName : b} //b = Promise {<pending>}
    };
  },
```

Comment: `getCitizen(id, name).then(result => here is the result)` ... or inside another `async` function ... `result = await getCitizen(id, name)` - i.e. there are exactly two ways to get data once Promises get involved ... `async/await` or `promise.then`

Comment: @Jaromanda X can you expand on this in an answer? I can only ever get the async/await solution to work. When i use promise.then, it always returns undefined.

Comment: @QrowSaki - you're probably doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just put it in an `created()` hook like:

```
data: function () {
 return {
      citizenselected: {CName : b} //returns [object Promise] instead of string
    };
},
created() {
    getCitizen(this.$route.params.citizen_id, this.$route.params.citizen_name).then(res => {
       this.citizenselected.CName = res;
    });
}
```

Is there an reason that you put your methods outside of your vue instance?

Comment: I am aware of the use of the created() hook but I am looking for an alternative way without using the created() hook. i.e. can be loaded from data: function().

Comment: @Joseph `created()` is the common way. Is there a good reason you want to avoid it?

Comment: https://www.ma-no.org/en/programming/javascript/crud-operations-using-vue-js-a-basic-example - this website shows a way without the use of created(). I just followed it and I thought it can be done also.

Comment: @Joseph yea they use synchronous code. you have asynchronouse code here. and to be honest this post doesnt look serious

Comment: @Joseph vue.js is a "framework" so you should work in that frame and not outside of it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return a promise from your getData function. You can either do that explicitly, or with then syntax.

```
// not async, then syntax
function getData(id, name)
{
  try {
    axios({
         url: 'http://localhost:44375/api/citizen/GetCitizenById',
         method: 'get',
         timeout: 8000,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
         params: 
         {
          citizen_id: id, 
          citizen_name: name
         }
     }).then((res) => {
           if (res.status == 200) {
             console.log(res.status)
           }
           return res.data;
        });
 }
 catch (err) {
     console.error(err);
 }

}
```

```
//explicit promise, async
async function getData(id, name)
{
  try {
    let res = await axios({
         url: 'http://localhost:44375/api/citizen/GetCitizenById',
         method: 'get',
         timeout: 8000,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
         params: 
         {
          citizen_id: id, 
          citizen_name: name
         }
     })
     if(res.status == 200){
         // test for status you want, etc
         console.log(res.status)
     }    
     // Don't forget to return something  
     return new Promise((resolve) => {resolve(res.data)});
 }
 catch (err) {
     console.error(err);
 }

}
```

Comment: the getCitizen method will not wait for getData method to return result if it is not marked as async.

Comment: Does the async (explicit Promise) method work at least then?